# How do i make python choose randomly one line after the first line of a file?

Tags: python

Is it possible to make python to randomly choose a line EXCEPT the first line of the file which is reserved for something else? Any help appreciated :)

```
with open(filename + '.txt') as f:        
    lines = f.readlines()         
    answer = random.choice(lines) 
    print(answer)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slice the array:

```py
answer = random.choice(lines[1:])
```

Answer (score 3):

You may also *reserve* the 1st line beforehand and freely use random selection:

```
with open(filename + '.txt') as f:
    reserved_line = next(f)   # reserved for something else
    lines = f.readlines()
    answer = random.choice(lines)
```

Comment: Good one, but I would rather do `reserved_line = lines[0]` after reading all lines (atleast that's more readable).

Comment: @Austin, in that case `lines` list would store a redundant 1st line and should be skipped in further potential slicing (conditions may vary)

Comment: If you use `next`, use `lines = list(f)` to read the remaining lines; don't mix iteration with directly file access.

Answer (score 1):

`f.readlines()` doesn't read *every* line from a file; it reads the *remaining* lines starting with the current file position.

```
with open(filename + '.txt') as f:        
    f.readline()  # read but discard the first line     
    lines = f.readlines()  # read the rest
    answer = random.choice(lines) 
    print(answer)
```

Since a file is its own iterator, though, there is no need to call `readline` or `readlines` directly. You can instead simply pass the file to `list`, using `itertools.islice` to skip the first line.

```
from itertools import islice

with open(filename + '.txt') as f:
    lines = list(islice(f, 1, None))
    answer = random.choice(lines)
```